# How to display stack trace on a caught exception?

Tags: java, tomcat, stack-trace

I have a generic function that prints exceptions (using log4j):

```
private void _showErrorMessage(Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getClass() + ": " +  e.getMessage() + ": " + e.getCause() + "\n" +  e.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```

Instead of seeing the stack trace I'm seeing:

```
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@49af7e68
```

How can I view the stack trace of the exception properly?

## update

log.error(e) <- shows the error, but doesn't show stack trace

Comment: Calling `log.error(e)` in log4j calls the wrong version of the method ( http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object%29 ). The JavaDoc for this method even mentions that fact: "WARNING Note that passing a Throwable to this method will print the name of the Throwable but no stack trace. To print a stack trace use the error(Object, Throwable) form instead."

Comment: call log.error(e,e) will do the job ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use the [ExceptionUtils#getFullStackTrace](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getFullStackTrace(java.lang.Throwable)) method of [Jakarta Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Comment: @codemonkey, you can search yourself for the ExceptionUtils in your favourite search engine: my answer was to use an existing library. I can't maintain all links I have posted in SO. Now, the answer from Joachim sounds better than mine :) Please read it.

Answer (score 78):

Your logging framework should have the ability to log exceptions, so simply passing the exception to the proper `.error(Object, Throwable)` call should be enough:

- [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) [can do it](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#error-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Throwable-)
- [commons logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) [can do it](http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html#error(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable))
- `java.util.logging` [can do it](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log(java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable))

If your logging framework can't do that, or you need the stack trace in a `String` for any other reason, then it becomes a bit harder. You'll have to create a `PrintWriter` wrapping a `StringWriter` and call `.printStackTrace()` on the `Exception`:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String stacktrace = sw.toString();
```

Comment: when i pass the exception to log.error, it just shows the error message with no stack trace. using log4j

Comment: That means that you called the wrong version. There's `error(Object)` and `error(Object,Throwable)`. Calling the first version will effectively call `toString()`.

Comment: @Joachim, the way to handle exceptions with log4j - which he mentions to be using - is to log using log.error(String, Throwable) and let log4j handle the stack trace.  The asker clearly isn't aware of that.

Comment: @Joachim, sorry. It appears that the log4j-information was added in the edit made after your answer.

Answer (score 21):

Have you tried?

```
private void _showErrorMessage(Exception e) {
    log.error("Hey! got an exception", e);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Throwable.getStackTrace`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) returns an array of [`StackTraceElement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)s, hence the `toString` method is returning a textual representation of the array itself.

In order to actually retrieve the stack trace information, one would have to go through each `StackTraceElement` to get more information.

Answer (score 4):

You could also look at the Guava libraries from Google.

`Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(Throwable throwable)`

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to your question is that you should call Log4J like this:

```
private void _showErrorMessage(Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getClass() + ": " +  e.getMessage() + ": " + e.getCause(), e);
}
```

Although I would dispense with the call to e.getCause() because the stacktrace will give that to you anyway, so:

```
private void _showErrorMessage(Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getClass() + ": " +  e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

ExceptionUtils is fine if you really need a string of the stacktrace, but since you are using Log4J, you lose a lot by not utilizing its built in exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

[Exception Stacktrace logging](http://www.mymemoryleak.com/2014/01/exception-stacktrace-logging/) shows two methods for this purpose, one based on Apache Commons and another using the standard JDK method.